# Dynamically mapped components from array in state are not updating even after state changes

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-state

I'm mapping an array in the state to build  dropdowns dynamically. I have two working methods to add and remove values in the array. When I remove and add values to the array I want the UI elements to also update as the state changes. Addition works but deletion fails every time. I have confirmed the array in the state is being changed correctly but I can only ever delete the newest component instead of a specific one. Thanks for your help.

```
 //
 handleToggle() {
    return this.state.AdditionQueryArray.map((array, index) => {
      let key = array.key;
      return (
        <div>
          <Select
            onChange={(e) => this.AdditionalOperatorHandleChange(e, key)}
            options={this.state.OperatorOptions}
            placeholder="Select Operator"
            menuPortalTarget={document.body}
            menuPosition={"fixed"}
          />
          <button onClick={() => this.deleteAdditonalQuery(index)}>
            Delete
          </button>
          {this.forceUpdate}
        </div>
      );
    });
  }

  createAdditionalQuery() {
    const state = this.state;

    let key = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);

    var copyArr = [...this.state.AdditionQueryArray];

    copyArr.push({
      key: key,
      field: "fieldDefault",
      property: "propertyDefault",
      PropValue: "Propvalue",
    });
    this.setState({
      AdditionQueryArray: copyArr,
    });
  }

  deleteAdditonalQuery(indexVal) {
    var state = this.state;

    var copyArr = [...this.state.AdditionQueryArray];

    if (indexVal > -1) {
      copyArr.splice(indexVal, 1);
    }

    this.setState({
      AdditionQueryArray: copyArr,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.createAdditionalQuery}>Add Query </button>
        {this.handleToggle()}
      </div>
    );
  }
  ////
```

Comment: `{this.forceUpdate}` seems very suspect, but then again, you aren't even calling the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shallow copy and `array.splice` is interesting way to remove an element from an array by index. I suggest using `array.filter` instead, it's much more clean. I suggest always using functional state updates when updated arrays stored in state, especially when used in callbacks attached in loops. This avoids any stale state enclosures.

```
deleteAdditonalQuery(indexVal) {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    AdditionQueryArray: prevState.AdditionQueryArray.filter(
      (el, index) => index !== indexVal
    ),
  }));
}
```

Similarly in the add handler, use a functional state update.

```
createAdditionalQuery() {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    AdditionQueryArray: prevState.AdditionQueryArray.concat({
      key: Math.random().toString(36).substring(7),
      field: "fieldDefault",
      property: "propertyDefault",
      PropValue: "Propvalue",
    }),
  }));
}
```

In `handleToggle` remove the "dead" force update code, it shouldn't be necessary. It's not being invoked anyway. Don't forget to add a React key to the outermost element being mapped.

```
handleToggle() {
  return this.state.AdditionQueryArray.map((array, index) => {
    const key = array.key;
    return (
      <div key={key}> // <-- add React key!
        <Select
          onChange={(e) => this.AdditionalOperatorHandleChange(e, key)}
          options={this.state.OperatorOptions}
          placeholder="Select Operator"
          menuPortalTarget={document.body}
          menuPosition={"fixed"}
        />
        <button onClick={() => this.deleteAdditonalQuery(index)}>
          Delete
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Also nice beard bro